# Compare a cell to a list and if match mark a different column in Excel

Tags: excel, match, excel-2010

I have a question about some cell formatting. I am trying to identify if a cell's (non-numerical) value  is contained in a list of cells. If the cell matches, mark a different column with a Y, otherwise mark it with a N. My question is very similar to [the question asked here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/643707-using-if-to-compare-1-cell-to-another-list.html), but when I use `=If(Isnumber(Match(I2,'SALT, WOD, Champion Members'!A$2:A$39,0)),"Y","N")`, it doesn't give me correct results. I also tried `=IF(I2='SALT, WOD, Champion Members'!A$2:A$39,"Y", "N")`, but started giving me errors after I extended the formula past the 40th row.

Any assistance is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to explain what "doesn't give me the correct results" means. I am also not sure what, exactly, you mean by "extend the formula". I appreciate you probably mean by dragging it down, but it requires a little more explanation.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean by "doesn't give me the correct results" is that cells that should be filled with N are being filled with Y, and vice versa. As for extending the formula, I meant dragging it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there are a couple of things that need to be clarified.

First, formatting is about how things in excel looks and putting `Y` or `N` isn't about formatting.

Now, if I understand the formula you tried to use, you have a sheet named `SALT, WOD, Champion Members` and in this sheet in the column A, there is the list of many non-numerical values you need to check against a value in cell `I2`. If this value is in there, you want to get `Y`, otherwise `N`.

The first formula you used should be giving you the results you seek for any value in the list within cells `A2` to `A39`, so this is what you might be considering being incorrect. Maybe it's safer to take the whole column, meaning `A:A`:

```
=if(isnumber(match(I2, 'SALT, WOD, Champion Members'!A:A, 0)), "Y", "N")
```