# Match name and copy row from sheet 1 to sheet 2 on corresponding column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I asked a very similar question to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371401/compare-a-cell-to-a-list-and-if-match-mark-a-different-column-in-excel), but I am trying to identify if a cell's numerical value is contained in a list of cells on a different sheet. If the cell from sheet A matches a cell in sheet B, mark a different column in B with a corresponding row in sheet A, otherwise leave it blank. An example is below:

```
Sheet A

Column A | Column B
-------------------
   1        John
   2        Sue
   4        Bob
```

I would like the corresponding Sheet B to populate Column B like this:

```
Sheet B

Column A | Column B
-------------------
   2         Sue
   3        
   4         Bob
```

---

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(I2, 'SALT, WOD, Champion Members'!A:A, 0)), "Y", "N")
```

I have been using the above answer to populate a different column in the same workbook, and I'm thinking I can maybe use this formula, but instead of "Y" or "N", somehow preserve the row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `VLOOKUP` as already mentioned. But you will need to use another function to check for existence of the value, else you will get #N/A against ID 3

I used `COUNTIF`

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$4,E2)=0,"",VLOOKUP(E2,$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE))
```

[image: VLOOKUP]

Answer (score 1):

Use the [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/look-up-values-in-a-range-HP005228952.aspx) function:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1;Sheet1!A:B;2;FALSE)
```

Where A1 is the value you want to look up, Sheet1!A:B is the original sheet with the data.

Comment: This gives `#N/A` error against ID 3 as there is no matching entry.

Comment: Yeah, but you can easily check for N/A in another column: =if(isna(B1);"";B1)