# I have two matching cells in two sheets and want to create a new column with a value I already have for when both cells match

Tags: excel, merge, dataset

I have two databases with some equal columns. One database is my main one that lacks 1 specific column that the other database contains. I want to get the missing column in my main database.

What I want to do is that when value X of the corresponding columns in the two databases is equal, then I want to create a new column, equal to the column which I have in my alternative database in my main database.

In other words, as I have a hard time explaining.

Database 1 has column A and this is the database I want to keep using
Database 2 has column A and B.

I want to get column B in database 1.

But most important, the values of column B correspond to values in column A, so I need to make sure these values correspond also in database 1.

The values of ''ID number for each executive / company combination'' correspond to the other dataset. When the values is equal the value of ''match_effect'' should be taken over in a new column.

[image: Excel picture]

Comment: Have a look [Match name and copy row from sheet 1 to sheet 2 on corresponding column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728135/20643658)